# Definition of unitary operators

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $\phi, \psi \in \mathcal{H}$ be some element from a hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and $U$ a linear operator $U: \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$. Does

$$ \forall \phi: \| U \phi \|^2 = \| \phi \|^2 = (\phi, \phi) $$

imply that $U$ is unitary? I suspect not, and I think I have to require the more general relation:

$$ \forall \phi, \psi: (U \phi , U \psi) = (\phi, \psi)$$

However, I cant see why this is more general then the condition above. In other words, is there a $U$ that is not unitary and fulfills the first equation but not the second?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both above conditions are equivalent and define an isometry. A unitary operator satisfies 
$$ U^*U = UU^* = I,$$
while the isometry satisfies only $V^*V=I$. 
So for a unitary operator apart from the condition which you wrote we also have it for its adjoint, that is, 
$$ \left<U^*x, U^*y\right> = \left<x, y\right>.$$

**Example of a map which is an isometry, but not unitary:**

Let $V \colon \ell^2 \rightarrow \ell^2$ be given by $V(x_n)=(y_n)$, where $y_1=0$ and $y_{n+1}=x_n$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $V$ is an isometry, that is 
$$ \left<Vx, Vy\right>=\left<x,y\right>,$$
but it fails to be a unitary operator (it is not onto).

**Proof that both conditions which you wrote are equivalent:**

One direction is obvious.

Let us assume that the following holds
$$ \|Vx\| = \|x\|$$
we would like to show that for any $x$, $y \in \mathcal{H}$ we have also
$$ \left<Vx, Vy\right> = \left<x, y\right>.$$

Let $x$, $y \in \mathcal{H}$ and let $r \in \mathbb{C}$, then
$$ LHS=\| x+ry\|^2 = \|V(x+ry)\|^2 = \| Vx + rVy\|^2=RHS.$$
Now note that 
$$LHS = \|x\|^2 + 2 \mathrm{Re} \overline{r}\left<x,y\right> + \|y\|^2$$
and
$$RHS = \|Vx\|^2 + 2 \mathrm{Re} \overline{r}\left<Vx,Vy\right> + \|Vy\|^2=
\|x\|^2 + 2 \mathrm{Re} \overline{r}\left<Vx,Vy\right> + \|y\|^2.
$$
Therefore we obtain that
$$\mathrm{Re} \overline{r}\left<Vx,Vy\right>=\mathrm{Re} \overline{r}\left<x,y\right>.$$
We end the proof by first taking $r=1$ and then taking $r=i$, note that if your Hilbert space was over $\mathbb{R}$, then you would just take $r=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your proof and particular nice example. Is $V^* (x_n)=(y_n), y_n=x_{n+1}$? Then I also see why $V V^*=1$, but $V^* V \neq 1$!

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Hello sir, may I ask you a question: I'm reading Friedberg linear algebra 4th ed. page 379, the definition of unitary operator is divided into two cases: finite/infinite dimensional, and in finite case the def is $||T(x)||=||x||$, but this is not the real def of unitary right? it's just that $||T(x)||=||x|| \iff T^*T=TT^*=I$ in finite case and from your answer the def of unitary should be $T^*T=TT^*=I$? Appreciate your reading.

Comment: In infinite-dimensional spaces, unitary operators are bijective with the inverse being equal to their adjoint. For a finite-dimensional vector space $X$ and every linear operator $V \colon X \rightarrow X$, injectivity (of $V$) is equivalent to its surjectivity. So (in finite-dimension) the condition $\|Vx\| = \|x\|$, which yields that $V$ is injective, implies also its surjectivity. This would not be that case if $X$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space (look at the counterexample in my answer above). I hope that it is clear, now.