# Why do we need the polarization identity to show the simple relation $U:H\to H$ is unitary if and only if $||Ux|| = ||x||$ for all $x \in H$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

An operator $U:H\to H$ is unitary if and only if $\|Ux\| = \|x\|$ for all $x \in H$. I read that the proof that $\|Ux\| = \|x\|$ implies $U$ is unitary depends on the polarization identity. But it seems more elementary than that; can we not just say that
$$
\|Ux\| = \|x\| \Longleftrightarrow (Ux,Ux)^\frac{1}{2} = (x,x)^\frac{1}{2} \Longleftrightarrow (Ux,Ux) = (x,x),
$$
and therefore $U$ is a unitary operator. Why do we need the polarization identity?

Comment: Those equivalences all hold, but none of them is the definition of unitarity, which is about preserving arbitrary inner products.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Its ok, I noticed right after posting that we have to show $(Ux,Uy) = (x,y)$ for all $x,y \in H$!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Definition of unitary operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007703/definition-of-unitary-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this theorem helps:

> *Theorem*: If $T \in L(H)$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space then the following are equivalent:
>
> $1)T^*T=I$
>
> $2)<Tx,Ty>=<x,y>$ forall $x,y \in H$
>
> $2)||Tx||=||x||$ forall $x \in H$

$Proof$

$1) \Rightarrow 2)$

If $T^*T=I$ then $<T^*Tx,y>=<x,y>, \forall x,y \in H \Rightarrow <Tx,Ty>=<x,y>, \forall x,y \in H$

$2) \Rightarrow 3)$

For $y=x$ we have that $||Tx||^2=||x||^2 \Rightarrow ||Tx||=||x||$

$3) \Rightarrow 1)$

Forall $x \in H$

$<Tx,Tx>=<x,x> \Rightarrow <T^*Tx,x>=<x,x>=<Ix,x> \Rightarrow <(T^*T-I)x,x>=0 \Rightarrow T^*T-I=0 \Rightarrow T^*T=I$